# Why is there a difference in how postgres treat cast and '::' expression differently?

Tags: postgresql

Someone explain to me why there are two different results for seemingly similar expressions

```
db=> select cast(8/3.0 as integer) as cast1, 8/3.0::int as int1;
 cast1 | int1
-------+------
     3 |    2
```

Comment: I don't think postgres treat them differently (except for the trivial parentheses: the operator `::` has a high priority, so your expressions will be the same with `(8/3.0)::int`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 8/3.0 is 2.6 =>CAST to integer = 3
- 8/3.0::int = 8/(3.0::int) = 8/3 = integer division which outputs 2